# Considerations for AWS Athena dataset? TSV

Tags: sql, performance, csv, amazon-web-services

I am planning a analyse a TSV File with below paramenters

- Approx 200-225 columns (String, Boolean, Timestamp, int, decimal)
- Around 200000 rows of data

The file size will come to 350-400 MB

My queries here

- Do I need to split into multiple files for better performance?
- Should I partition it ? For reduced scans and saving costs?
- How can I speed up select queries? How does indexing working in TSV Files?
- Will Snappy compression reduce the size of the file? 30%-40% (File will be 280-300 MB)
- Does converting it to Apache ORC will help in reducing size?

As I am new to AWS Athena, any suggestion or feedback is welcome?

Answer (score 1):

I think Athena wouldn't have any issues processing a 400 MB file. You can probably split these into two files of equal sizes (yes, use compression too) and then query. In general - if the split files are too small (less than 128 MB) and there are too many files like that, you might find that it actually takes more time with split files. For your total file size, I think you won't find any difference even if it were a single file.

But converting TSV to columnar formats will give you the best performance. Try converting TSV/CSV to Parquet and query. Its unlikely that all of your queries are `select * from` so go ahead and parquet. Check the user guide for [converting to columnar formats](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)

Comment: Many thanks for suggestions, is it possible to convert from CSV/TSV to ORC/paquet with a CLI tool or Java program? I think ORC has Java API - https://orc.apache.org/.... reason being it will be a huge overhead to spin a new EMR Instance just for conversion

Comment: If you are doing this on AWS already, it makes sense to use EMR cluster to convert from CSV to parquet. [This link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html) has instructions on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

This is a very small dataset for Athena and it's likely optimization won't be worth the effort unless many people are continuously using it.   Time may be better spent if all you're doing is going from 1.6 seconds - .8 seconds a query.  To answer your questions:

**Do I need to split into multiple files for better performance?**  No. It would likely hurt performance at this scale.

**Should I partition it ?** For reduced scans and saving costs?  Unlikely, hard to envision a scenario where it's worth it.

**How can I speed up select queries? How does indexing working in TSV Files?**  There's not much you can do if you're staying in a TSV file with regards to sorting etc.

**Will Snappy compression reduce the size of the file? 30%-40% (File will be 280-300 MB) .** It will.

**Does converting it to Apache ORC will help in reducing size?**  Yes.  This would be the most worthwhile action.  The minimal effort of converting to ORC or Parquet  would likely give you greater gains than any of the other points above.